# Issue with firebase V9. The firestore does not work while testing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Homescreen.js

```
getRequestedPosts = async () => {
    const postsCollection = collection(db, 'Posts');
    const q = query(postsCollection);
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const postList = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
        this.setState({ isPostLoaded: true });
        this.setState({ Posts: postList });
    });
}
```

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"; 
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxxx-xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx-xxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789",
    appId: "1:1111111111111:web:xxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "x-xxxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 7):
FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
WARN  [2023-03-06T14:19:04.745Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.2): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {"defaultPrevented": false, "g": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 2, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": "PQy6RJr8jT4jkcQOCIjHl8O-CLVAIBnve9I6pEwuqcI", "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": 91, "F": [U], "Fa": 12, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "7q32bwA7dICDr1R3DTaHUg", "K": 45000, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": 0, "W": 74080, "Y": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel", "aa": 3, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 9, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": "", "o": null, "oa": null, "pa": 8, "s": null, "sa": 404, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": [U], "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/synergy-de1b7/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "status": 1, "target": {"A": true, "J": null, "R": [Circular], "g": {"$": true, "$a": 5000, "A": 2, "B": null, "C": 0, "Ca": "PQy6RJr8jT4jkcQOCIjHl8O-CLVAIBnve9I6pEwuqcI", "D": "gsessionid", "Ea": 91, "F": [U], "Fa": 12, "G": 0, "Ga": false, "H": true, "Ia": [ud], "J": "7q32bwA7dICDr1R3DTaHUg", "K": 45000, "L": false, "M": true, "O": true, "P": false, "R": 0, "U": [Object], "V": 0, "W": 74080, "Y": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel", "aa": 3, "ab": false, "ba": false, "bb": false, "cb": 2, "eb": 9, "fb": 10000, "g": null, "h": [pd], "i": [Array], "j": [Sb], "l": [Z], "la": [Object], "m": null, "ma": undefined, "na": "", "o": null, "oa": null, "pa": 8, "s": null, "sa": 404, "u": null, "ua": undefined, "v": null, "va": [U], "wa": 600000}, "h": {"database": "projects/synergy-de1b7/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "type": "c"}
```

No data is getting from firestore. But when I build the app using './gradlew assembleRelease --warning-mode all' Everything works perfect, smooth and amazing. What should I do? I am really tired of this. I really need a serious help. I have nearly tried every possible thing. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message tells you you are offline, are you?

Comment: No i am not offline and everything works on production build but don't work while testing build.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is not with Firestore but with your build process? Are you using the same Firestore configuration in test and production?